# Python deal with \\ in file path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to backup a file in a Network drive, but the file path is

```
\\H-HP\Users
```

i knew I need to change the \ to /,

```
import shutil
shutil.copy2('C:/Users/HP/red.xlsx', '//H-HP/Users/red.xlsx')
```

I got a error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '//H-HP/Users/red.xlsx'"

I wonder if that's a Permission issue or the way I handle \ is wrong.

Comment: I think you can try `os.path.join()`

Comment: How about `"\\\\H-HP/User/red.xlsx"`?

Comment: When you do the same copy via the command line, what happens?  Your path may be fine, you just have bad permissions.